# What is the maximum speed Hadrons can move?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, neutrons, protons

How fast can protons and neutrons move. Also, how fast can the quarks they are made of move?

Comment: Any speed less than speed of light.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$c-\epsilon$, for any $\epsilon>0$.